# How to Grant Limited Local Disk Access to File on Local Disk in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Looking for a way to allow a user to upload a client cert and keep it on their machine via chrome extension.  The idea is the cert lives on a user's local disk at rest and the extension merely reads the file to sign requests. Is something like this possible? I've seen people use `file://<path-to-local-file>` in `manifest.json` to allow file access permissions, but is there a way to let the user specify this explicitly, so the scope of disk acess is limited to 1 file?

Comment: You can use the new [File System API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) and store the file's handle in IndexedDB. However, there's probably no need to use a file at all if you only need its contents, which you can store directly in extension's storage.

Comment: Isn't it true that the extention storage is not secure and all other extensions/sites have shared access to this? The idea is for the extension to be a dumb pipe to a secure file on a user's machine.

Comment: Generally not true, [more info](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/W9heTiMDaDw/m/aF7-WfnkCwAJ). How exactly will you use that file?

Comment: I want to sign web requests with a certificate the extension merely points to, so it's not actually uploaded anywhere.  Ideally, a user could just grant access to a specific path on their machine.

Comment: And how will you do it? I don't see such API for extensions on desktop, only on ChromeOS and those don't use files either.

Comment: I want to do this by allowing the user to grant access to a specific path on disk. I.e. use a file picker to select cert file in a folder and allow chrome extension to read that file from disk. Basically, I just need secure access to a local file. I'm not sure if this is possible however.

Comment: Reading a file is not a problem (use File System API) but how exactly do you plan to use its contents afterwards?